# Laravel custom Auth not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Instead of the custom user model I've setup a new model in:

> app\src\employee\Employee

Now when I say this for testing:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
         if(Auth::attempt($request->parameters[0]))
         {
             return 'ingelogd!';
         }
         else {
            return 'false';
         }
    }
```

It always return false. But the credentials are right! I've changed the following in:

> app\config\auth.php

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => src\employee\Employee::class,
        ],
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

dd output:

```
array:2 [
  "email" => "jamie64@gmail.com"
  "password" => "testtest"
]
```

Credentials are right checked it multiple times.

Comment: what is dd($request->parameters[0]); value ?

Comment: @LearningMode sorry about that that was just a test I will remove that.

Comment: @jamie print your $request->parameters[0] here!

Comment: First of all, maybe it will help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/replacing-the-laravel-authentication-with-a-custom-authentication. How your model look like? Does it have all required fields?

Comment: And, by the way, attempt has following signature `public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false, $login = true)`. Make sure, that `$request->parameters[0]` is really an array of required credentials.

Comment: @GinoPane yes it's an array.

Comment: @LearningMode Please check my edit for that.